# Link value label thousands separator

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I'm using `sankeyNetwork` from [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3). When I plot my data, if I hover the mouse on the sankey links the link label appears, and the thousands separator in this label is a comma. I would like it to be a point.

Here is an example:

```
library(networkD3)

nodes <- data.frame(name = c('a','b'))
links <- data.frame(source = c(0), target = c(1), value = c(12000))

p <- sankeyNetwork(
  Links = links,
  Source = "source",
  Target = "target",
  Value = "value",
  Nodes = nodes,
  NodeID = "name",
  fontSize = 12,
  nodeWidth = 30,
  iterations = 0
)

p
```

[image: output]

thankss!!

Xevi

Comment: It is hardcoded into the JavaScript. You would either have to modify the underlying JavaScript or somehow override the custom format function [here](https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/sankeyNetwork.js#L96-L100).

Comment: "You would either have to modify the underlying JavaScript": How can I do that?

Comment: Fork the repo, change the “,” to a “.”, install your modified version of the package.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by rewriting the link titles with `htmlwidgets::onRender`...

```
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)

nodes <- data.frame(name = c('a','b'))
links <- data.frame(source = c(0), target = c(1), value = c(12000))

p <- sankeyNetwork(
  Links = links,
  Source = "source",
  Target = "target",
  Value = "value",
  Nodes = nodes,
  NodeID = "name",
  fontSize = 12,
  nodeWidth = 30,
  iterations = 0
)

customJS <- '
function(el,x) { 
    var link = d3.selectAll(".link");

    var format = d3.formatLocale({"decimal": ",", "thousands": ".", "grouping": [3], "currency": ["", "\u00a0€"]}).format(",.0f");

    link.select("title").select("body")
        .html(function(d) { return "<pre>" + d.source.name + " \u2192 " + d.target.name +
            "\\n" + format(d.value) + "<pre>"; });
}
'
onRender(p, customJS)
```

[image]